# How to determine the location of the clogged spot in floor drain using a powered drain auger, and auger tip suggestion?

Tags: basement, drain, drainage, clog, drains

I have a basement floor drain that clogs and backs up a bit (but do slowly drain all the water). I used a powered auger attempting to clear it but without total success (it drains better but not as good as when it's working perfectly). I pulled out some black grease like substance and hair. I wonder if I can determine how far along the opening of the floor drain the clog is located?

And also, is there a auger tip I should use to better clear the clog?

Comment: Sure. Measure the auger. The best bit depends on the nature of the clog. Any sign of roots?

Comment: No root. Mainly black sticky thing and little hair.

Comment: Just about any bit should clear that as long as it's 3/4 the size of the pipe or better.

Comment: the auger might have found someplace else to go that doesn't help; length along doesn't tell you as much as it should unless you know the piping layout well. if you have organic blockages, foaming pipe cleaners should help.

Comment: I have tried drano with no success, any specific brand I should consider?